# DIV TABLE (4x4)

Tags: html, css-tables

I am looking for a div table, with 4 columns and 4 rows.

I would like the width to be 100%, I would like to insert images and text into each div.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why not use <table> then? Also set up a jsfiddle where we see what you have tried so far

Comment: change display properties for divs like here http://jsfiddle.net/amcPM/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a grid with Html and CSS with DIVS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014209/how-do-i-make-a-grid-with-html-and-css-with-divs)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to show tabular data, just use a table. If you want it to be responsive you might use this as a layout: **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/j6cN8/1/)**

```
.row{
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.cell{
    float: left;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 24%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

Note: I set the minimum width of a cell to 100px so it won't be too small - that's the advantage of using divs instead of a table. If you don't won't the structure to break in small display, you really should use a table.