# Aligning divisions in the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a webpage using HTML5, CSS3. 
I have four lists, that I have separated out in 4 different divisions.Another division #position_calls is the parent of all the above mentioned divisions.

I wish to arrange these four lists in a 2*2 array formation, where each box should have same height. I have tried doing this using "float" keyword but that didn't work out well.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/18yway8m/).

```
#tech_calls{
    float:left;
    border:2px solid green;
    width:49%;
    height:50%;
    margin:auto;
}
#quantech_calls{
    float:right;
    border:2px solid green;
    width:49%;

}
```

I refrain from using "position" keyword as that might hinder with responsive pages.

Also, I can't understand why the parent red border of div #position_call doesn't covers whole area (including its child divs). But removing float property from all child div, it works fine. [JSFIDDLE.](https://jsfiddle.net/18yway8m/1/)
So what float has to do with this?

Any help would be appreciated.

I am familiar with Javascript if that helps, Thanks!

Comment: The parent container should have an `overflow:hidden` and it should render fine. https://jsfiddle.net/ImAtWar/18yway8m/3/

Comment: I'd suggest you use bootstrap. It makes things much easier.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014209/how-do-i-make-a-grid-with-html-and-css-with-divs

Comment: @ImAtWar I understand the use of overflow:hidden but I can't understand how it helps here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a display property and one parent div for the top two divs and one for bottom two divs. Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/18yway8m/4/).
So,

`<div style="display:flex">
 tech_calls Div
 quantech_calls Div
</div>`

Similarly for the other two.

Comment: I don't downvote but it's probably because you have no code (and worse: some `enter code here`) in your answer. In the future your link may not be available anymore and thus your answer is then worthless.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but I'd say using display: flex; is generally not a good answer because IE will probably not handle it.

Comment: @Wavemaster Okay. I have updated it. I didn't understand why the editor wouldn't let me remove the `enter code here`, then read the description and added some code.

Comment: @apokryfos supported by IE 10 and above.

Comment: There's a typo in your `dsiplay'. Also you shouldn't add the css in the html tag directly if you don't need it because it can't be overwritten easily.

Comment: @RahulSharma http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox indicates that while it's supported, IE 10 and 11 have some bugs with it (which can be a pain to build workarounds on).

Comment: @RahulSharma can you explain why the border in parent division didn't cover whole area in the question?

Comment: @Wavemaster thanks for pointing out the typo. I agree with you, but I just wanted to give an idea how to do it. Adding it inline or in a separate file is upto the OP. I personally use it in an external css.

Comment: @RaghavMotwani because I didn't touch your existing css. You can play around with your settings to get the desired result (like removing the border etc.). Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/18yway8m/8/). You can have it this way or further customize it.